# Why is an inflatable balloon inside a fuel tank not used to prevent fuel from "sloshing around"?

Tags: fuel, design-alternative, liquid-fuel, cryogenics, fuel-system

After seeing all the Starship failures, having something with a membrane keep things in place seems like an obvious solution. Has it been considered or tested - or do we simply lack a material that is elastic at the (cryogenic) temperatures required? What would it theoretically take? What subjects would you need to study to develop such a material?

Comment: A similar idea is using moving diaphragms for the tank ends.  No image link but [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/Ehp2Y_JWVO8?t=357) shows an example (link is to point in video where diagram is shown).

Comment: @BenCrowell I presume that's a reference to the various Starship prototypes.  SN1, SN2, ...

Comment: @BenCrowell ...with SN standing for Serial Number.

Answer (score 22):

They do!

Many propellant tank, especially those required to work in zero-g environments, do use just such a bladder-inside-a-tank for the fuel. [Typically monopropellants for thrusters.](https://www.space-propulsion.com/spacecraft-propulsion/hydrazine-tanks/hydrazine-tank-overview.html)
[image]

It completely removes the requirement for Ullage of the propellants, but adds complexity, cost, mass and failure modes.

Additionally, flexible bags are a bit hard to make at deep cryogenic temperatures.
Additionally, flexible bags that can contain 200 tons of cryogenic liquid sloshing around under 5 g of acceleration are.... simply impossible to manufacture.
I don't think we will ever have the technology to make a soft bag that can hold 1000tonnes (200 tonnes under 5g) of cryogenic liquid that is sloshing around.

For interest: take a peek at this. Work on developing a bladder that *is* cryogenic compatible. But max size very much small.
https://www.geekwire.com/2020/ancient-art-origami-provides-pathway-building-better-tank-rocket-fuel/

Comment: It's worth noting that the ones that operate long term aren't cryogenic fuels, so...

Comment: Do any boosters use these?

Comment: @OrganicMarble From the first link: "Our bladder tanks are used on the 400 N Attitude and Orbital Control System (AOCS) of all versions of Ariane 5 and in the VEGA 200 N Roll and Attitude Control System (RACS)."

Comment: Those are RCS systems. Not the booster tankage.

Comment: Aahh... it's the math again :-D

Comment: I was thinking more of instead of just pressurizing the tank with another gas, to save on the other gas and weight, by adding a pouch that can sit on top of the fuel... rather than putting the fuel in the pouch.

Comment: @Dagelf  So what would inflate the pouch? And how is that substantially different from just pressurising the tank directly?

Comment: Wouldn't having a membrane provide more control over which side of the tank the secondary propellant is on?